# How to select the adgroup of a specific account when having a larger account hierarchy?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I couldn't figure out how to select the adgroup of a specific account.

In my adwords account I have a three level nesting, so I have **Account1**, under this Account I have **Account2** and then I have **Account3**. In **Account3** I have a lot of campaigns, which adds I want to manipulate, so I am trying to select a specific adgroup.

I came up with the code below, which unfortunately tries to get the AdGroups for **Account1** and not **Account3**.

```
AdWordsApp.adGroups()
  .withCondition('Name = "' + 'AGName' + '"')
  .withCondition('CampaignName = "' + 'CampName' + '"')
  .get()
  .next();
```

I can't figure out how to make the code run for **Account3**.

I suppose that I have to select somehow the desired account and then run the code on it, but I have no idea how to do that.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You must use MccApp not AdWordsApp, and use de the account selector of the MccApp as is explained here:

[AdWords Scripts Docs](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/mccapp/mccapp_managedaccountselector)